# how to get selected values of an array of dropdownlist box using jquery

Tags: jquery

how to get selected value of array of drop down list box using jquery?
I have uploaded the code that i have tried. doesn't work for drop down.
thanks in advance for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Below is a screenshot of me using jQuery (thanks to the jQuery inject add-on) to fetch the selected value from the form item.

in brief: `$("select option:selected").val()`

[image: demonstrating getting the selected value from a select]

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select.foo option:selected').val(); // get the value from a dropdown select
```